# WCF service and COM interop callback

Tags: multithreading, wcf, com, interop, mta

I have a COM object that creates an instance of a WCF service and passes a handle to itself as a callback. The COM object is marked/initialized as [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading).

The problem being every instance of the WCF service that makes a call to the callback occurs on the same thread, so they are being processed one at a time which is causing session timeouts under heavy load. The WCF service is session-based, and I am  not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate the callback implementation with the `CallbackBehavior` attribute and set `ConcurrencyMode` to `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`. The default setting is `ConcurrencyMode.Single` which restricts to one service callback at a time. Of course if you do that you must ensure your callback implementation is thread safe.